# Web Cartography how to, CartoDB - Mapbox

Tags: web-mapping

I have to prepare an online map like the following http://www.oikoskopio.gr/map/ but I don't know what program they use. Can I do something like that with CartoDB or Mapbox; with these services you can make a map but the TOC, can I do something like this in CartoDB or in Mapbox?

Comment: It seems to be done using OpenLayers

Comment: For the background is Bing maps. but I dont know about the table of contents, the menu is only with code or a ready application.

Comment: Agree with iant that map client has been developed in part using OpenLayers.  There is also some PHP, possible MapScript PHP, as the tile service and other layers are being provided by MapServer services.